# Share wifi connection with ethernet

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ethernet, bridge, connection-sharing

I have PC1 and PC2, PC1 is connected to wifi and PC2 is connected to PC1 with ethernet, I set PC1 wired connection with the option "Shared with other computer".
 With this configuration, my PC2 have internet, but PC1 & PC2 ethernet ips are like 10.40.0.X and PC1 wifi ip is 192.168.1.X

I want that ethernet ips of PC1 and PC2 become 192.168.1.X

If I change PC1 ethernet ip in static with 192.168.1.X, PC2 ip become that what I expect but internet doesn't work.

Im running linux.
I think that I should need to set up a bridge, but when I do it my PC2 have no internet.

Comment: Bridging Wi-Fi stations to Ethernet is, in general, not possible. Only using tricks like MAC address NAT or multiple virtual Wi-Fi stations can you achieve something similar.

Comment: related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/3063/share-wireless-connection-with-wired-ethernet-port

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bridge between wireless and ethernet on PC1 won't help you here because PC2 would not get an IP address from the wifi.

Instead you can setup IP forwarding on PC1 and masquerading on its wifi interface.
Then PC2 can access the internet using the wifi address of PC1.

To configure IP forwarding for IPv4 you would call `sysctl` like this:

```
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

To add masquerading on PC1 you would call something like this if you have installed iptables:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Instead of `wlan0` you have to use the name of your wifi device. You can find the name for instance using the following command:

```
ip addr show
```

Look for your wifi IP address in the output. The name of the interface is given a few lines above after the number of the interface.

**Edit:** Added configuration for IP forwarding.

Comment: Can you tell me, if you can, how to do masquerading wifi on PC1 please?

Comment: -j MASQUERADE is the command

Comment: @Mathias Weidner, you forgot the instructions for enabling ipv4 forwarding on pc1. Decent answer otherwise.